# NumPy array row differences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, scipy

I have a NumPy array `vectors = np.random.randn(rows, cols)`. I want to find differences between its rows according to some other array `diffs` which is sparse and "2-hot": containing a `1` in its column corresponding to the first row of `vectors` and a `-1` corresponding to the second row. Perhaps an example shall make it clearer:

```
diffs = np.array([[ 1,  0, -1],
                  [ 1, -1,  0]])
```

then I can compute the row differences by simply `diffs @ vectors`.

Unfortunately this is slow for `diffs` of `10_000x1000` and vectors `1000x15_000`. I can get a speedup by using `scipy.sparse`: `sparse.csr_matrix(diffs) @ vectors`, but even this is `300ms`.

Possibly this is simply as fast as it gets, but some part of me thinks whether using matrix multiplications is the wisest decision for this task.

What's more is I need to take the absolute value afterwards so really I'm doing `np.abs(sparse.csr_matrix(diffs) @ vectors)` which adds ~ `200ms` for a grand total of ~`500ms`.

Comment: A full minimal reproducible example would help (unless Jerome's answer is all you need). I am not sure what is possible to optimize - Jerome assumed it is possible to "compact" `diffs` but that is not so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can compute the row differences by simply diffs @ vectors.

This is very inefficient. A matrix multiplication runs in `O(n*m*k)` for a `(n,m)` multiplied by a `(m,k)` one. In your case, there is only two values per line and you do not actually need a multiplication by 1 or -1. Your problem can be computed in `O(n*k)` time (ie. `m` times faster).

> Unfortunately this is slow for diffs of 10_000x1000 and vectors 1000x15_000. I can get a speedup by using `scipy.sparse`.

The thing is the input data representation is inefficient. When `diff` is an array of size `(10_000,1000)`, this is not reasonable to use a dense matrix that would be ~1000 times bigger than needed nor a sparse matrix that is not optimized for having only two non-zero values (especially 1 and -1). You need to store the position of the non-zeros values in a 2D array called `sel_rows` of shape `(2,n)` where the first row contains the location of the 1 and the second one contains the location of the -1 in the `diff` 2D array. Then, you can extract the rows of `vectors` for example with `vectors[sel_rows[0]]`. You can perform the final operation with `vectors[sel_rows[0,:]] - vectors[sel_rows[1,:]]`. This approach should be drastically faster than a dense matrix product and it may be a bit faster than a sparse one regarding the target machine.

While the above solution is simple, it create multiple temporary arrays that are not cache-friendly since your output array should take `10_000 * 15_000 * 8 = 1.1 GiB` (which is quite *huge*). You can use Numba so to remove temporary array and so improve the performance. Multiple threads can be used to improve performance even further. Here is an untested code:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(int_[:,::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(diffs, vectors):
    n, k = diffs.shape[0], vectors.shape[1]
    assert diffs.shape[1] == 2
    res = np.empty((n, k))
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        a, b = diffs[i]
        for j in range(k):
            # Compute nb.abs here if needed so to avoid 
            # creating new temporary arrays
            res[i, j] = vectors[a, j] - vectors[b, j]
    return res
```

This above code should be **nearly optimal**. It should be **memory bound** and able to **saturate the memory bandwidth**. Note that writing such *huge arrays* in memory take some time as well as reading (twice) the input array. On x86-64 platforms, a basic implementation should move 4.4 GiB of data from/to the RAM. Thus, on a mainstream PC with a 20 GiB/s RAM, this takes 220 ms. In fact, the sparse matrix computation result was not so bad in practice for a sequential implementation.

If this is not enough to you, then you can use simple-precision floating-point numbers instead of double-precision (twice faster). You could also use a low-level C/C++ implementation so to reduce the memory bandwidth used (thanks to non-temporal instructions -- ~30% faster). There is no much more to do.